# Writing from persistent data path to streaming asset

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, streaming

I'm trying to get bytes from Application.persistentDataPath to streaming asset and save it as an mp4 file but my code doesnt work.

Here it is :

```
IEnumerator streamit(){

        string filePath ="file:///"+ Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Locomotive Part 1.mp4");
        Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
        string converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;



        WWW www = new WWW(converted);
        Debug.Log (www.error);
        yield return www;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath+"/example.mp4", FileMode.Append))
            foreach(byte data in www.bytes){
                fs.WriteByte (data);


            }


}
```

So what am I doing wrong ? Its not working on both IOS and Mac

Comment: You should not have the "file:///" on the front, it is already contained in the data path.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found my problem.

Everything that doesn't work because of empty spaces on the source path. In **IOS, you have to change empty spaces with "%20" whenever you are sending a path.**

Thanks Anyway !